# Is there a way to make G++/clang++ compile times as fast as MSVC?

Tags: c++, g++, llvm, clang++, compile-time

For my tests I need to compile some thousand C++ files which have a lot of code in common. Because not all compilers are conformant (or more permissive) I execute all my tests with g++, clang++ and msvc on windows and linux.

To improve compile times I use already precompiled headers for common code. Additionally I wrote a small preprocessor app to allow "unity builds" (combine *.cpp files into a single *.cpp file).

Currently I get the following compile times (random test case):

- MSVC with PCH: 0.573 secs
- MSVC without PCH: 5.367 secs

(approx 10 times)

- Clang with PCH: 5.221 secs
- Clang without PCH: 7.225 secs

(approx 1.4 times)

- G++ with PCH: 3.099 secs
- G++ without PCH: 5.826 secs

(approx 1.9 times)

Unfortunately my code contains a lot of templates / template instantiations which seem to be only "saved" in the Microsoft PCH.

Do you know any way to get similar compile times for g++ and clang++? Do you have any suggestion how to improve my compile times?

Here you can see the chrome/clang trace (-ftime-trace and pch):
[image: Clang time trace with precompiled header]

Comment: How did unity builds affect this? Another general technique is to build in parallel. The simplest is the "embarrassingly parallelism" of separate files. This is in some tension with unity builds, but if you batch your unity build into multiple chunks rather than all in one file, the two techniques can work together. You can further extend this further by using other machines via IncrediBuild or icecc.

Comment: With "unity builds" you don't have to instantiate the templates in every translation unit. Because of all my test cases I have already 100% CPU load.

Comment: PS, You are considering MSVC your baseline, but you can do this same sort of build analysis using vcperf. [See here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/improving-code-generation-time-with-cpp-build-insights/).

Comment: Right. I understand the benefits of a unity build. Are you saying that your numbers above reflect the use of a unity build? How many unity chunks did you use? How many processors are you using during the build? Do you have additional machines available that you could further parallelize the build?

Comment: Take a look at [ccache](https://ccache.dev/).

Comment: Also, which versions of each tool are you using?

Comment: Currently I run my tests on my dev machine which has 12 (logical) cores and 6 physical ones. Yes the numbers above reflect the the use of a unity build. I use g++-11 (trunk), clang++-10 and Visual Studio 16.7 Preview 6.0.

Comment: I don't know if I understood ccache really - but what I need is a way to "save" the template instantiations.

Comment: My machine has 32 GB RAM and two 1 TB SSDs. But my CPU is the limiting factor. Perhaps I could buy another machine - but I would prefer to avoid this redundant workload.

Comment: How many chunks is your unity build in? Is the full CPU capacity of your machine dedicated to building, or are you running tests concurrently while building? (If testing while building, you may want to find a way to pipeline these operations.) So far, we've only talked about extrinsic sources of improving build performance. Someone may still speak to compiler-specific build flags that could have some impact. I'm not an expert there, so I'll defer to others.

Comment: Currently my unity build app produces a single cpp file - no chunks. This file includes just some headers (std-library and my own library which is a header-only library). These headers are more or less all included in the PCH. After build I usually execute the compiled apps, too. But those need only some milliseconds. All is done in parallel -> 100% CPU load. You nearly can't move the mouse :-).

Comment: How would I go with ccache? Create cpp files with explicit instantiations and extern templates? It sounds complicated...
@Jesper: Have you done this? It seems to be more relevant for C - code without templates and a lot of code in translation units.

Comment: @Bernd I *always* use ccache. It's trivial to set up and it speeds up rebuilds significantly by caching and reusing object files when the source has not changed (so the actual compiler never gets called at all). It doesn't work as well with unity builds as without, since with a unity build almost any change requires an actual rebuild of the object files. For non-unity builds it's a life saver (remember to configure a *large* cache size - I use 100GB).

Comment: If you have only one file for your unity build, how are you getting 100% CPU usage for all processors? Is the compiler itself using multiple threads on the single translation unit?

Comment: I have a lot of tests which I run in parallel - so enough workload. I would assume that clang, gcc... do something in parallel, too.
To wait some seconds is not really an issue - but if you have to do it some thousand times it becomes an issue. Especially if you see that it is doable in less than a second (see MSVC).

Comment: That's where pipelining the build and tests and breaking the unity build into chunks could potentially help. It would add some overhead to your build -- instantiating templates multiple times, but since it's in parallel, it's still potentially a speedup.

Comment: I found this: https://reviews.llvm.org/D69585 - perhaps this helps (it changes pch handling for clang-cl). I'll check it...

Comment: Good news: with clang 12.0.0 / trunk I was able to reduce the compile time for the test to two seconds. (I build it on my own - but it takes some time...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least in the current clang trunk that there is some notable progress to improve compile times in combination with templates and precompiled headers / modules.

Perhaps gcc implements something similar - we will see.
But thanks for your comments.